# Google APIs Force English Response Message

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Sheets API to perform actions against the users' spreadsheets after they authenticate, and some of the actions raise errors like:

```
This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells
```

or

```
You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit
```

In both cases, the API returns `HttpError 400 code and the string value is the only way to distinguish from one another and knowing the specific issue. No error code related to the issue is provided. The problem is that the string comes in different languages according to the user account language settings, making it really hard to map all language possibilities. For example, the message bellow is the equivalent to the one above, but in Spanish instead:

```
Estás intentando modificar una celda o un objeto protegido. Si necesitas realizar cambios, comunícate con el propietario de la hoja de cálculo para que quite la protección
```

Is there any parameters on the APIs that enforce the response to be always in a specific language?

Comment: I don't think this parameter exists. Are you sure you are not able to distinguish between the different possible errors, based on the method that is throwing the error and based on other fields in the error object? (eg code, reason, etc). Another option would be using a service account with domain-wide delegation, if all users are from the same domain.

Comment: @Iamblichus. Yes pretty sure. I've gone through every response attribute and there is nothing that tells me. Code is 400 and Reason is BAD REQUEST

Comment: Are you getting this kind of error (`BAD REQUEST`) in production? It's the two errors you are mentioning in your question? In this case, I guess you could tell them apart by checking whether the error message contains `5000000` or not?

Comment: @Iamblichus, yes from production. Maybe I could distinguish from 5000000 for this specific error, but other errors don't have this information like the other example.

Comment: @Iamblichus, we are a SaaS company so all users are from different domains.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I tried changing a user account language settings to Spanish (following [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047)) and then calling an API; the returned error message is in English. Can you provide reproduction steps for this?

Comment: I have used the Oauth credentials from the user and performed the request call using his credentials from Python build client. By doing that, I get  the error message in the user's language

Comment: Also, we log the error messages in BigQuery where we found variations of the above messages in German, Dutch and French as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the example I reproduced locally is set to a Spanish timezone and locale.

Comment: I tried reproducing this using the Python library as mentioned, as well as with a Spanish timezone and locale, and still got the error messages in English. Not sure what I might be missing.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. Here I recorded a vídeo reproducing the issue:
https://www.loom.com/share/da14c19747de4a6dade8d45cf392c335